# Django views.py request and query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a contact page for my website. The contact form is working but I want to add a background image to this page (which is saved in the database).But how can I combine my email(request) and a query to get the image ?

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm


def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('./success')
    return render(request, "contact/email.html", {'form': form})

def success(request):
     return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Background(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='./background/', default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'contact'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the image on your view:

```
def get_background():
    try:
        background = Background.objects.get(name="your image name") # add your filters where to get the image
        if background.image and background.image.url:
            return background.image.url
    except Background.DoesNotExist:
        return


def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
...
...
# add the background to context
return render(request, "contact/email.html", {'form': form, 'background_img': get_background()})
```

And in your HTML (it's just a exemple, always try to style your site with a separate css file):

```
...
<div {% if background_img %}style="background: url('{{background_img}}') center no-repeat;"{% endif %}>
...
```